Solving the recurrence $a_{n}=3a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+1$
can you help me to find some solution?
$$a_{n}=3a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+1$$
I did it like this:
$$a_{n}-3a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}=0$$
then
$$a_{n}=c_{1}\cdot 2^{n}+c_{2}$$
But then I'm not able to find solution where on right side is $1$.
Thank you so much!

Hint: Put $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$.

What methods of solving recurrences do you know?

Have you thought about the structure of the set of solutions? If $(\alpha_n)_n$ and $(\beta_n)_n$ are two solutions, what can you say about $(\alpha_n-\beta_n)_n$?

Either you rewrite the recurrence relation as in Mostafa's answer (because the terms turn out to be telescoping in the right way) or you can consider an ansatz. Since the inhomogeneous term is constant, one would usually consider a constant ansatz, but it wouldn't differ from the homogeneous solution $c_2$ you found already, that is why you can use a polynomial ansatz instead of the form $\alpha n$.

we have :
$$a_{n}=3a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+1
$$
Therfore:
$$a_n-a_{n-1}+1=2(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+1) $$
this implies that :
$$a_n-a_{n-1}+1=(a_1-a_0+1)2^{n-2}$$
Therfore:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a_{k-1}+1)=(a_1-a_0+1)\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k-2}$$
Therfore:
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2}(a_1-a_0+1)(2^n-1)+a_0-n$$
